# Why parameter can be passed to constructor by assignment operator at object initialization？

Tags: c++

```
class a {
    a(int b);
}
main(){
    int b=5;
    a tempa=b;
}
```

How does this work?

I came across this problem in a HW?

Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Please post some actual code that you've compiled and run.

Comment: Woah... the font for `() {} ; ?` doesn't match the rest of the code. How'd you pull that off? (Not that you should, it just looks weird)

Comment: @Borgleader these are fullwidth characters. Not excessively useful with a monospace font anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constructor like the one shown in your question could be called a *conversion* constructor.

It allows the compiler to take a value of the argument type and convert it to an instance of the class.

In your example, the line

```
a = b;
```

is equal to

```
a = a(5);
```

(Well, with the exception of the conflict of having both a class and a variable named `a`)

If you want to disallow it, you have to make the constructor *explicit*

```
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(int);
};
```

Then the compiler can not use the constructor for conversions as the one described above. You have to *explicitly* use the constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot, some programmer dude.